# Adding links to movies on Google Keep

Tags: google-keep

Since Google Keep doesn't support adding movies (unlike WhatsApp) - can I link to a movie on my SD card (even as a regular text link like "keep:\\DCIM\25-02-2018-Foo.bar")?

**Note**: If it's a big movie, adding it to google drive (or similar upload sites) can be a problem. I just want a link.

Comment: [Link Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkssaver.thelinksbox) is an alternative but you can't use keep to access

Comment: Keep doesn't support hyperlinks to media stored on device from Google search. It doesn't say not supported but there is no way showing how it can be done